# Multiple Authentication Sources in Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

Is it possible to have multiple authentication sources enabled in Redmine.

This is to say that I can login using both my google apps account and/or my existing redmine username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can mix and use at the same time internal redmine accounts, [OpenID](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineSettings#Allow-OpenID-login-and-registration) and [LDAP](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineLDAP).

Comment: Can we use them simultaneously? Basically I want to set an internal authentication password when we are using OpenID access.

Comment: I think I get now what you mean: Yes, you can use them simultaneously, but no, you can't login with an OpenID user using an internal password. Each user is tied to one single authentication source.